# Cool, visually-transmissible uses of Prolog

Tags: prolog, visualization, logic-programming

I will be teaching only one lecture on basic Prolog to students with little to no experience in programming. I'd like them to see that programming and Prolog can be used in the real world, perhaps even to do cool things.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130097/real-world-prolog-usage) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759877/can-you-get-a-job-thanks-to-your-prolog-skills/) threads, but I cannot find anything that is visually appealing that I can show them when we wrap up the lecture.

Do you have any suggestions for cool applications that use Prolog? I'm especially looking for something that can be shown as a video or slideshow.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! It was difficult not to go with Watson as an answer but the other examples were very helpful in looking at visually-oriented applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to highlight the uses of prolog and use audio-visual media merely for presentation purposes, combining the following 2 links might do it:

[Natural language processing with prolog in the IBM Watson system](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/ALP/2011/03/natural-language-processing-with-prolog-in-the-ibm-watson-system/)

[IBM's Watson supercomputer destroys all humans in Jeopardy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFR3lOm_xhE)

Answer (score 2):

[InFlow](http://www.orgnet.com/inflow3.html) is written in Prolog. You may browse through the examples and / or contact the author for details. [VisiRule](http://www.lpa.co.uk/vsr.htm) might also help.

Disclaimer: I have not used either InFlow or VisiRule, but I do use WIN-Prolog which is the environment used for both programs.

Answer (score 2):

See:

http://personnel.univ-reunion.fr/fred/Enseignement/Prolog/index.html

under "La librairie clpfd", there are links to 3 finite domain constraint animations (N-Queens, Sudoku, Knight Tour) that are used in this class.

Answer (score 2):

[Dynalearn](http://hcs.science.uva.nl/projects/DynaLearn/software/) is implemented in Prolog and has animations.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Visirule. It is, as far as I can tell (and I've researched this topic quite a lot) a unique visual programming tool (I don't know of any other visual tool that is easily reduced to a turing-complete language). I have implemented a trouble-shooting website with it along with various other solutions. Highly recommended- version 5 coming out soon too.